# Wordpress: How to place a widget area INSIDE the menu

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation, widget

I've done extensive searches on this issue. My problem is that I want to place a widget area inside the Wordpress menu/navigation bar. what I have found is a solution on how to place a search bar inside a Wordpress menu, but i want to instead  place a widget area inside the Wordpress menu.

Here's the solution for the search bar one:
http://www.wpinsite.com/code-snippets/include-the-search-form-inside-wp-nav-menu

Comment: Link to wpinsite search form inside wp nav no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your menu's selector is something like

```
.menu .page-item-1
```

And suppose your widget's selector is something like

```
#text-1
```

You can use jquery to move the widget into the menu item by doing this:

```
$(".menu .page-item-1").appendTo("#text-1");
```

You'll probably have to clean up the css to get it to format nicely, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a year old question but since there's no answer I will chip in for the people who come here through Google.

Don't bother I've come across a number of custom solutions which I tried to implement into a theme for my client but in the end, something is off - be that responsiveness, hard to edit for the end user or some other minor bugs. Just use the free plugin Max Mega Menu. I wish I could take the four hours of my life back -> you can save them though.